# Simple Good-Turing Probabilities higher than old probabilities

Tags: r, probability, predictive-models, natural-language, smoothing

I've implemented Simple Good-Turing to get new probabilities of unigrams on my Corpus. Everything works fine.

I'm just confused on how come the probability of a word after the Good-Turing discount be higher than before?

```
> head(train.SGT1, 10)
  term frequency new.frequency percent.frequency      new.p     tag
1   the     71271      71270.15        0.04779577 0.04792401 unigram
2    to     41288      41287.15        0.02768857 0.02776262 unigram
3   and     35902      35901.15        0.02407661 0.02414092 unigram
4     a     35550      35549.15        0.02384055 0.02390423 unigram
5    of     30297      30296.15        0.02031778 0.02037196 unigram
6     i     24730      24729.15        0.01658444 0.01662856 unigram
7    in     24559      24558.15        0.01646976 0.01651358 unigram
8   for     16497      16496.15        0.01106322 0.01109246 unigram
9    is     16014      16013.15        0.01073931 0.01076768 unigram
10 that     15534      15533.15        0.01041741 0.01044492 unigram

> P0
[1] 0.02653376

> sum(train.SGT1$new.p)+P0
[1] 1
```

The new.p is higher than p until the 483rd row than it starts to get discounted

```
>tail(train.SGT1, 5)
             term      frequency new.frequency percent.frequency     new.p
69996         wallman         1     0.4638831      6.706202e-07 3.119278e-07
69997     wallmounted         1     0.4638831      6.706202e-07 3.119278e-07
69998     wallofsound         1     0.4638831      6.706202e-07 3.119278e-07
69999          wallop         1     0.4638831      6.706202e-07 3.119278e-07
70000       walloping         1     0.4638831      6.706202e-07 3.119278e-07
```

Why the higher frequency unigrams (lower frequency of frequencies) get their new probabilities higher than before?
is this ok or a glitch in my code?

Answer (score 1):

In the formula to calculate new counts, you add 1 to the count, than multiply it by the ratio of the frequency of its frequency and the frequency of the next frequency. For high counts, this ratio is 1 - which means you simply add one to the count.